# Проверка элемента в многомерном массиве php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив - получаю данные из бд.
мне нужно проверить есть ли многомерный массив в другом массиве. как это сделать?
`in_array` не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Если искать среди элементов на первом уровне - цикл и is_array. Если на любом уровне вложенности рекурсия и is_array